# Drawing text with OpenGL / GLFW / FreeType produces white rectangle instead of glyphs

Tags: opengl, text, glfw, freetype2

I'm trying to write a function which will render a string at some (x, y) coordinate in OpenGL. This application is only going to render things in 2D, which is why I'm initializing the matrix mode and ortho projection the way I am. I'm using GLFW to initialize the window and poll for events:

```
int render_loop()
{
    int r;
    GLFWwindow *window;

    int width;
    int height;

    if(!glfwInit())
        return -EINVAL;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(S_WINDOW_W, S_WINDOW_H,
        "My Window", NULL, NULL);

    if(!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -EINVAL;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Initialize the GL viewport.

        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-0.5f, (width - 1) + 0.5f,
            (height - 1) + 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        // Draw some text.

        FT_Face font = get_font();

        render_text("f", 5, 5, font);

        // End GL rendering, swap the buffer, and poll for events.

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

And here's my function to render text:

```
int render_text(const char *t, int x, int y, FT_Face f)
{
    int ret = 0;

    GLuint *textures;

    size_t i;
    size_t length = strlen(t);

    FT_GlyphSlot g = f->glyph;

    // Allocate a texture for each character.

    textures = (GLuint *) malloc(sizeof(GLuint) * length);

    if(textures == NULL)
    {
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto done;
    }

    glGenTextures(length, textures);

    // FreeType glyphs are 1-byte greyscale, so we can't use alignment.

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Render each character...

    for(i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        // Render this particular character using FreeType.

        if(FT_Load_Char(f, t[i], FT_LOAD_RENDER))
            continue;

        // Make the current glyph's texture active.

        glActiveTexture(textures[i]);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[i]);

        /*
         * To prevent artifacts when a character is not rendered exactly on
         * pixel boundaries, clamp the texture to edges, and enable linear
         * interpolation.
         */

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);

        // Load the texture.

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_ALPHA, g->bitmap.width,
            g->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            g->bitmap.buffer);

        // Render the texture on the screen.

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

            glTexCoord2i(0, 0);
            glVertex2i(x + 0, y + 0);

            glTexCoord2i(g->bitmap.width, 0);
            glVertex2i(x + g->bitmap.width, y + 0);

            glTexCoord2i(0, g->bitmap.rows);
            glVertex2i(x + 0, y + g->bitmap.rows);



            glTexCoord2i(g->bitmap.width, 0);
            glVertex2i(x + g->bitmap.width, y + 0);

            glTexCoord2i(g->bitmap.width, g->bitmap.rows);
            glVertex2i(x + g->bitmap.width, y + g->bitmap.rows);

            glTexCoord2i(0, g->bitmap.rows);
            glVertex2i(x + 0, y + g->bitmap.rows);

        glEnd();
    }

    // Free our textures and we're done.

    glDeleteTextures(length, textures);
    free(textures);
done:
    return ret;
}
```

The result is that I get a white rectangle at (5, 5) instead of the character. I think the problem is that OpenGL is interpreting the alpha data incorrectly when I call `glTexImage2D`? I'm not totally sure how to set it up properly, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[21.070 How do texture objects work?](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/texture.htm#text0070)

> Texture objects store texture maps **and their associated texture parameter state.** They allow switching between textures with a single call to glBindTexture().
>
> ...
>
> The following functions affect and store state in texture objects: glTexImage*(), glTexSubImage*(), glCopyTexImage*(), glCopyTexSubImage*(), **glTexParameter*()**, and glPrioritizeTextures(). Since the GLU routines for building mipmap pyramids ultimately call glTexImage*(), they also affect texture object state.  Noticeably absent from this list are glTexEnv*() and glTexGen*(); they do not store state in texture objects.

So, `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`/`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` state is stored with the texture object.

You're setting them *before* you have a real texture object bound so all you're doing is diddling texture object `0`.  Not very helpful.

All your newly created textures will have the default `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` set for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`.  But you aren't providing any mipmaps.  Which results in the white [incomplete textures](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture) you're seeing.

**Solution**: Move your `glTexParameter()` calls to *after* `glBindTexture()`.

Comment: This is definitely one problem with my code, but after fixing it, I still get the same white rectangle instead of a glyph. I've updated the code in my OP.

Comment: I believe you also have to enable texturing with `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`.

Comment: I've added `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)`, and I still get the same white rectangle. I've noticed that I can change the color of the rectangle from white to a different color with `glColor3f`; does that indicate that it's not an incomplete texture but some other problem?

Comment: The `glActiveTexture()` call you also added looks wrong. It takes a texture unit as an argument, not a texture name. You shouldn't need it at all as long as you're only using a single texture. But if you want the call, it should be `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)`.